# rxjs/ajax response Cannot assign to read only property 'taskData' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, angular, ajax, rxjs

In an angular application I have created a service that fetches a json object from the backend via GET.

When I use this `fetch` code block, everything works fine:

```
fetchNode(nodePath: string): Promise<CrxApiNode> {
const {token} = this.authInfo$;
return fetch(`${nodesUrl}?path=${encodeURIComponent(nodePath)}`,
  {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    }
  }
).then(res => {
    return res.json();
}).catch(e => {
  console.log('error');
});
```

}

When performing the same request with rxjs/ajax:

```
  loadNode(nodePath: string): Observable<CrxApiNode> {
const {token} = this.authInfo$;
  // this leads to the error
return ajax.getJSON(`${nodesUrl}?path=${encodeURIComponent(nodePath)}`, {
  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
}).pipe(
  map(node => {
    return node;
  }),
  catchError(error => {
    // here the error occurs: Cannot assign to read only property 'taskData' of object '[object Object]'
    console.log('error: ', error);
    return of(error);
  }));
```

}

I get the error (thrown by ajax(...):

```
"TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'taskData' of object '[object Object]'
at XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1939:39)
at XMLHttpRequest.desc.set [as ontimeout] (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:1292:24)
at AjaxSubscriber.setupEvents (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:78731:23)
at AjaxSubscriber.send (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:78652:18)
at new AjaxSubscriber (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:78634:14)
at AjaxObservable._subscribe (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:78605:16)
at AjaxObservable._trySubscribe (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:77010:25)
at AjaxObservable.subscribe (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:76996:22)
at MapOperator.call (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:82439:23)
at Observable.subscribe (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:76991:31)"
enter code here
```

Since I'm fairly new to rxjs I'm struggling with analyzing the error - What's the difference here and why is the rxjs variant not working as expected?

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you're returning `of(error)` from `catchError` while your return type defined for the whole chain is `Observable<CrxApiNode>`.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you catch the error and log it. As a result the error is now "gone".

In the second example, you catch the error also, log it also, but then the mistake happens.
"catchError" will catch an error from the stream and it will return a new VALUE (not an error) into the stream. The reason for that is, that you now are able to catch the error and replace it with a default value, to handle the error as smooth as possible for the user.

As a result, your stream now emits an error Object. Without handling it as an error. I assume somewhere later you are calling  "myEmitedValue.taskData". But "myEmitedValue" is not the JSON from your backend call, but the error object. Therefor there is no "taskData".

If you would like to "rethrow" the error, you can instead

```
return throwError(err)
```

I have created a stackblitz with a few [examples](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-stxttn).

Comment: Thanks for your help and the examples - I got the issue with returning the error object, But the error happens during the ajax call in method 2 and I don't get why the ajax fails with the error? The http request is performed correctly and also delivers a correct response which somehow leads to the error thrown by ajax.